# Почему с конца не берется последний символ?

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, циклы, срез

```
row = 'wtf?'
print(row[0:1])
print(row[-2:-1])
>> w
>> f
```

Почему с конца не берется последний символ? 
Как его взять без конструкции `row[-2:]`, так как все это в цикле.

Answer (score 1):

`row[start: stop : step]`

`start` - Начальный индекс среза. 
        Начальное целое число, `с` которого начинается разрезание объекта
        Если не указан, 
        используется индекс первого элемента 'разрезаемого' объекта' - `0`.

`stop` - Конечный индекс. Целое число, `ДО` которого происходит нарезка.
       Если не указан, используется индекс последнего элемента 'разрезаемого' объекта - `-1`.

`step` - Шаг выборки. Отрицательное значение позволяет строить срез из элементов в обратном порядке.

```
print(row[0])   # Первый символ
w

print(row[-1])  # Последний символ
?
```

---

**Update**

```
row = 'wtf?'

for t in range( 0, len(row)+1 ):
    if row[ t-2 : t ]: print(row[ t-2 : t ])

wt
tf
f?
```

Comment: for t in range(1,len(row)):
    #надо вывести два последних символа
print(row[-t-2:-t])
>> ft
>> wt

Comment: @ЕгорЛапицкий `print(row[-2:])`

Comment: это понятно, но тогда надо писать лишнюю конструкцию на первый символ потому что следующие должны быть  row[-t-2:-t].

Comment: @ЕгорЛапицкий я добавил вариант, проверьте

Comment: @JopaBoga что не так?

Answer (score 0):

Если уж обязательно задавать `start` и `stop` в срезе:

```
>>> s = 'wtf?'
>>> s[-2:len(s)]
'f?'
>>>
```

Comment: да, но если это for t in range(1,len(row)):, тогда выводит без последнего символа